# What to rename my order table?

Tags: language-agnostic, naming

I have a database table named `order`. It contains eCommerce orders. Problem is, that's a reserved word in MySQL, and while I can use back-ticks to prevent issues, it's probably a good idea not to use a reserved word.

I could name it `orders`. Problem is, that's a plural. The rest of my tables using the singular naming scheme. Also, there's [some debate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338156/table-naming-dilemma-singular-vs-plural-names) on using plurals for database table names, and most people seem to prefer using singular.

I could name it `order_details`, which is technically correct because each row contains details, as opposed to order_items where each row contains an item, but it's rather confusing.

I think naming things is hard, but also important. Order tables are very common and I hope this question, while specific, will be useful to future users.

**What should I rename my order table?**

Comment: I used the table name "users" with PostgreSQL; I think the reason was that "user" was a reserved word. I didn't see any problem with it being plural and others being singular.

Comment: I'd call it 'orders' because it contains orders.

Comment: @GrandmasterB, strangely enough, that is quite convincing.

Comment: Avoiding reserved word clashes and the pure logical *niceness* of it are two very good reasons to favour plural names for tables. The only con I can see - that it makes using automatic code generators and ORM tools a bit harder to configure - really doesn't seem anywhere near as important to me. Go plural. Change all your tables if you can easily update all the clients.

Comment: I like `OrderThatIsNotThatOrder`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally opinion based, but I'll throw in a couple of ideas.

I like `order_header` plus `order_details` which makes it clear how they fit together.

You could call it `sales_order` to distinguish between, say, a `purchase_order`, which is entirely different.  Or `customer_order` which makes it clear where the order came from.

Or you could keep the name `order` but use the database's syntax to distinguish it from a keyword. In SQL Server you'd use `[order]` and in MySQL you'd [use backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql), like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `order`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the type of order that it is, rather than trying to get cute with the names. Even if `order` was not a reserved word, this might come in handy in the future.

Consider:

- customer_order
- ecommerce_order

Answer (score 0):

Always avoid reserved keywords , consider dboorder, surely it is a database table I'd call it as dbo(database object (table_name) ie; dboorder or dbo_order